# Deploying a Flask app to hosting at godaddy

Tags: python

I am using Python/Flask Microframework. (http://flask.pocoo.org/) to build a small app. Tested the app locally and deployed it to godaddy and there I am seeing "ERROR 400" when going to the `URL`. I called their tech support and  they are saying the app will need index.html page and that their platform does not support python. Here is where I am loading the pages.

[image: mAIN.PY]

FYI, it runs in Amazon EC2.

Comment: Have you successfully deployed Python apps to your GoDaddy hosting previously? Does your [plan support](http://support.godaddy.com/help/article/7254/can-i-use-python-272-with-my-hosting-account) Python? Are you able to get a basic Python "Hello World" page working on GoDaddy without Flask?

Comment: I actually paid for a Godaddy upgrade to support Python when I wanted to start learning Python for web hosting until I discovered the free hosting solutions of Heroku and Google App Engine.  I found GAE to be easier to use.

Comment: Please put *code* in your question rather than *images* of code. (In this case, the actual code doesn't really matter.)

Comment: @StackUnderFlow, for Heroku you will have to learn git source control if you do not already use it.  It is worth learning though.  GAE was much easier for a noob like me.  My first experience was with Heroku, Python, Flask.  I eventually switched to GAE.

Comment: If you plan to continue to use GoDaddy instead of checking out one of @dansalmo's suggestions, I would recommend starting with a "Hello World" simply to ensure that you've got Python working properly with GoDaddy before you start introducing more complex dependencies. It's clear you can get everything running when you have full access to the machine, but shared hosting doesn't give you the same level of control, so it can be nice to add some extra sanity checks along the way in order to ensure that the scope of the problem is as narrow as possible.

Comment: @cjc343  thanks, yes i will do that and then take it from there.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Being on a shared environment means that you will most likely need to use CGI to deploy:

http://flask.pocoo.org/docs/deploying/cgi/

> On shared webhosting, though, you might not have access to your Apache
>   config. In this case, a file called .htaccess, sitting in the public
>   directory you want your app to be available, works too but the
>   ScriptAlias directive won’t work in that case:
>
> RewriteEngine On RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f # Don't interfere
>   with static files RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /path/to/the/application.cgi/$1
>   [L]

Comment: CGIHandler doesn't support python2.6 from now. FYI

Answer (score 0):

It is a bit tricky. I am starting a cPanel Deluxe account. The only way I have found is to install Python 3.x and then install virtualenv, and then use pip install requirements.txt to install what I need